# PHP - How to Display Detail Record Fields In Another Browser Window From A ListView

Tags: php, javascript, listview, master-detail

I have a ListView produce via PHP code:

```
   <?php do { ?> 
   <tr>
       <td width="20"><a href="edit_property_mktg.php?recID=<?php echo $row_rsProperties['recID']; ?>"> <img src="./images/small_pencil.png" /></a></td>
       <td width="20"><a href="view_property_mktg.php?recID=<?php echo $row_rsProperties['recID']; ?>"> <img src="./images/small_eye2.png" /></a></td>
       <td width="20">
         <form name="properties" method="post" action="properties.php?search=<?php echo $row_rsProperties['ms_address']; ?>">
           <button type="submit" name="properties"> <img src="./images/newsletter.png" /> </button>
         </form>
       </td>       
       <td width="250"><?php echo $row_rsProperties['ms_address']; ?></td>
       <td width="140"><?php echo $row_rsProperties['ms_city']; ?></td>
       <td width="140"><?php echo $row_rsProperties['ms_state']; ?></td>
       <td width="60" align="center"><?php echo $row_rsProperties['ms_zip']; ?></td>
       <td width="250"><?php echo $row_rsProperties['ms_mm_owner1']; ?></td>
       <td width="250" align="center"><?php echo $row_rsProperties['owner_phone1']; ?></td>
       <td width="250" align="center"><?php echo $row_rsProperties['expired']; ?></td>
       <td width="250" align="center"><?php echo $row_rsProperties['fsbo']; ?></td>
       <td width="250" align="center"><?php echo $row_rsProperties['ms_status']; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php } while ($row_rsProperties = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsProperties)); ?>
```

How would I get the click on the Edit or View anchors to open in a window (that was opened via javascript code after authentication?

PHP file (performed when the main menu is loaded):

```
<body onLoad="openDetailWindow()">
```

Javascript src .js file function:

```
function openDetailWindow() {
    window.open("_blank.php","LMS - Record Detail","fullscreen=0,menubar=0","false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Placed the following code inside of the anchor tag:

```
onclick="window.open(this.href, 'LMS - Record Detail',
'menubar=0,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0', 'false'); return false;"
```

So, now the  tag now reads as follows:

```
<td width="20"><a href="edit_property_mktg.php?recID=<?php echo $row_rsProperties['recID']; ?>" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'LMS - Record Detail',
'menubar=0,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0', 'false'); return false;"> <img src="./images/small_pencil.png" /></a></td>
```